# GZipping CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, gzip, yslow

I'm using YSlow to improve the speed of my site, and I'm having trouble with the "compress components with gzip" grade. I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript
```

But YSlow is saying

> There are 4 plain text components that should be sent compressed

```
* http://crewinyourcode.com/css/reset.css
* http://crewinyourcode.com/css/inner-pages/index.css
* http://crewinyourcode.com/script/css/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css
* http://crewinyourcode.com/js/inner-pages/index.js
```

How can I gzip the css and js files?

Also...I don't have access to the httpd.conf file.

You can see the problem at http://crewinyourcode.com

UPDATE:

Added

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

to .htaccess and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Look like that the problem is already fixed?

Comment: My YSlow is still giving me the problem.

Comment: Do hard refresh (`Ctrl+F5`) or clear browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have AddType lines for .css and .js?  It's pretty hard for Apache to automatically figure out the types by content alone -- they both look a lot like C code.

Try adding these lines to your .htaccess...

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

Comment: I disagree, I believe it is Stupid YSlow.

Answer (score 2):

> Added, and it didn't help

Works for me, I'm now getting `Content-Type: text/css` and `gzip` encoding, which wasn't happening before due to the missing type mappings. That's something that should really be fixed server-wide though; it is a very broken server that cannot serve stylesheets and scripts with the right type.

Incidentally you should use `text/javascript` for scripts, for proper browser compatibility. `application/javascript` is proposed as ‘better’ for various nitpicking technical reasons, but it doesn't have the support so you can ignore that. `x-javascript` is long gone.

Comment: Yeah, i was gonna have the AddType line say text/javascript and say "and change your AddOutputFilterByType line".  But eh.  It wasn't the problem at the time.